# what is the diff between rm -rf $TIGER/${LION}/${RABBIT}/* and rm -rf $TIGER/${LION}/${RABBIT}?

Tags: shell, scripting, ksh, csh

I need to understand the diff between `rm -rf $TIGER/${LION}/${RABBIT}/* and rm -rf $TIGER/${LION}/${RABBIT}` so that putting this in script won't produce the disaster making it to delete everything it can from root in case that the variables are not set. what is the safe way to use rm -rf in csh/ksh?

Thanks for help !!

Comment: Your two questions -- behaving safely if the variables are unset and understanding the difference between those two commands -- have nothing at all to do with each other.

Comment: ...by the way -- quotes are your friends. `rm -rf "$tiger/$lion/$rabbit"` would be less buggy if any of those variables contain spaces. (And using lower-case variable names is more conventional if the variables are neither shell builtins nor environment variables).

Comment: ...and there's no effective difference between `$foo` and `${foo}` in this command at all; you could leave out all the curly braces with no harm whatsoever.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, I think if the variables are unset rm -rf $TIGER/${LION}/${RABBIT}/* results ///* or /* that deletes all from the root that has permission to delete and rm -rf $TIGER/${LION}/${RABBIT} results rm -rf * wherever the pwd points. Do you agree?

Comment: No, I don't agree. `rm -rf $TIGER/${LION}/${RABBIT}` results in `rm -rf //`, which is exactly the same as `rm -rf /`. The other one results in `rm -rf //*`.

Answer (score 8):

Either of those commands would create a disaster if the variables were all unset; they differ only in whether they delete the directory itself, or its non-hidden contents.

If you want to be safe against deleting recursively from the root directory, explicitly test for that case and cancel:

```
[[ $TIGER && $LION && $RABBIT ]] || {
  echo "TIGER, LION and RABBIT must all be set; script exiting"
  exit 1
}
rm -rf ...
```

Answer (score 4):

This recursively deletes **all non-hidden files** *inside* the ${RABBIT} directory - ${RABBIT} directory is not deleted:

```
 rm -rf $TIGER/${LION}/${RABBIT}/*
```

**Note** hidden files (aka dot files) have filenames beginning with `.`. These are **not** matched with typical `*` expansion unless shell dotglob option is set.

So to delete **all** files (including hidden files) you could use `shopt` thus:

```
 shopt -s dotglob                   # turns shell option dotglob ON
 rm -rf $TIGER/${LION}/${RABBIT}/*  # Now deletes all (including hidden) files
 shopt -u dotglob                   # FYI - unsets or turns  dotglob OFF
```

This recursively deletes everything *including* the ${RABBIT} directory.

```
 rm -rf $TIGER/${LION}/${RABBIT}
```

Comment: Not everything, unless your shell's support for excluding hidden files from glob expressions is disabled.

Comment: Charles - edited answer in response to your informative comment.

Answer (score 0):

putting /* at the end will delete contents inside that directory

while only "/" will delete the directory itself as well as contents inside it.